# Selecting multiple columns in MySQL subquery and ORDER BY subquery date-time

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone have any idea how to select this.
Table messages look like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+--------+-------------------+
| id | fromUserID | toUserID | message | status |         dt        |
+----+------------+----------+---------+--------+-------------------+ 
|  1 |      1     |     2    |Hey,wh...|  seen  |2018-08-15 17:43:51|
|  2 |      2     |     1    |   Hey   |  send  |2018-08-15 17:45:51|
+----+------------+----------+---------+--------+-------------------+
```

MySql Query, I want used:

```
SELECT m.id, 
       (SELECT m.message, IF(m.fromUserID='1',1,0), m.status, m.dt 
        FROM messages m 
        WHERE (m.fromUserID='1' OR m.toUserID='1') AND (m.fromUserID=u.id OR m.toUserID=u.id) 
        ORDER BY m.dt DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS m,
       u.username,
       u.id AS usID
FROM messages m 
JOIN users u 
    ON u.id=IF(m.fromUserID='1',m.toUserID,m.fromUserID) 
WHERE (m.fromUserID='1' OR m.toUserID='1') AND
      m.dt>IFNULL((SELECT d.dt FROM deletechat d WHERE d.userID='1' AND d.withUserID=IF(m.fromUserID='1',m.toUserID,m.fromUserID)),'0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY m.dt
```

I used this, but I can not sort by date. And also if you find some ',', \', \" in the JSON string, I can't read it in PHP

```
SELECT m.id, 
       (SELECT CONCAT('{"message":"', m.message, '","myLast":"', IF(m.fromUserID='1',1,0), '", "status":"',m.status,'"}') 
        FROM messages m 
        WHERE (m.fromUserID='1' OR m.toUserID='1') AND 
              (m.fromUserID=u.id OR m.toUserID=u.id) 
        ORDER BY m.dt DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS m,
       u.username,
       u.id AS usID 
FROM messages m 
JOIN users u 
    ON u.id=IF(m.fromUserID='1',m.toUserID,m.fromUserID)
WHERE (m.fromUserID='1' OR m.toUserID='1') AND
       m.dt>IFNULL((SELECT d.dt FROM deletechat d WHERE d.userID='1' AND d.withUserID=IF(m.fromUserID='1',m.toUserID,m.fromUserID)),'0000-00-00 00:00:00')
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Please spend the time to format your queries so they are readable (as I have just done). You will find that you get a much better response to your questions that way.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I'm very busy

Comment: "I'm very busy" is not an excuse. You are asking other people to spend their time answering your question, so spend some of yours making it a good one.

Comment: update your question and add  the expected  result coherent with you data sample

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

> Question: I cannot sort by date

Instead of using GROUP BY you can use another SELECT to select from your current query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT m.id ...          /* <-- Your whole query */
   ...
   ORDER BY m.dt DESC        /* <-- At the end instead of GROUP BY user ORDER BY */
) as r LIMIT 1               /* <-- Select only the first result, which is the youngest */
```

---

> Question: if you find some ',', \', \" in the JSON string, I can't read it in PHP

In newer MYSQL versions there are JSON functions for that e.g. [JSON_OBJECT() or JSON_QUOTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html). Use like this:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('message', m.message, 'myLast', IF(m.fromUserID='1',1,0) FROM messages m
```

For older MySQL versions you could use [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to escape all the special characters like quotes.

Comment: This looks like a good idea, but when i run this query with JSON_OBJECT I got this error : #1305 - FUNCTION bosstest.JSON_OBJECT does not exist. My mysql version is : 5.0.12

Comment: That version is too old. Can't you just use `SELECT CONCAT(m.message, '#somestringdelimiter#', status,...)` and then split the string in PHP with `explode( '#somestringdelimiter#', $s)`? You would have to make sure that #somestringdelimiter# cannot be in the message text but that is easy to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot this idea is helpful